# Problem with my project on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to edit a project on android studio, but I keep getting these errors:

Could not HEAD 'https://chartboostmobile.bintray.com/Chartboost/com/tapjoy/tapjoy-android-sdk/12.8.0/tapjoy-android-sdk-12.8.0.pom'.
Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

also it is telling me to upgrade Gradle version, the current version is 4.2.2

Comment: Try Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project...

Answer (score 0):

> Could not HEAD 'https://chartboostmobile.bintray.com/Chartboost/com/tapjoy/tapjoy-android-sdk/12.8.0/tapjoy-android-sdk-12.8.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

This is caused by bad net connect. You could download the sdk directly from the [offical site](https://ltv.tapjoy.com/s/l#session/login?next=%252Fd%252Fsdks%252Fandroid%252Fdownload) and manually integrate it via referring to this [guide](https://dev.tapjoy.com/en/android-sdk/Manual-Integration).

> also it telling me to upgrade gradle version the current version is 4.2.2

This is only a suggestion and not mandatory.